# JDBC via BPXBATCH - how to get TSO-user credentials?

Tags: jdbc, db2, zos, j9, tso

I have a little java program that reads a db2 table via jdbc. This program is invoked via "tso bpxbatch myjavatool".

I wonder if there is the possibility to "pass" the username/password of my TSO user to the JDBC driver?

For example, if I connect to DB2 with a simple REXX script I don't have to specify my username/password again and DB2/RACF checks if my user is allowed to execute the SQLs.

Now my java tool is not running in my TSO address space but under the control of the J9 in the USS address space...

Is there also a way to automatically log in to DB2 with the current TSO user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know too much about BPXBATCH, but I assume you are still running under your own userid in the USS-address-space.

In your java-code you should be able to get your userid via

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
```

As for the password you could try using RACF-Passtickets instead. There is a library `IRRRacf.jar` in `/user/include/java_classes` and the corresponding javadoc in `IRRRacfDoc.jar` in the same directory. the code for generating the Passticket is rather simple:

```
IRRPassTicket generator = new IRRPassTicket();   
String ptkt = generator.generate(user,applid);
```

then just pass the passticket instead of the password and you should be fine.

Alas, there's several aspects you have to make sure of before using this approach:

- Set up RACF to use Passtickets for DB2  - it might already be configured, else you'll have to set up proper profiles in the PTKTDATA-class (See RACF-documentation for more details)
- Make sure each user running the code has the proper RACF authorization to use the r_ticketserv callable service (again, see RACF documentation)
- Find the correct application-name (`applid`) for your DB2-system. See the DB2-documentation about using passtickets.

Comment: IRRPassTicket is a very good idea, I haven't ever heard of that feature before. Nice. At the moment I am struggeling to find out the DB2 application id but I am confident that there is a way to extract it from somewhere...